# Container doesn't launch and logs are empty since updating Docker Desktop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

Yesterday I updated Docker Desktop (v.4.17.0) and today my Compose setup doesn't launch my main (Rails) container (`web`) - or rather it does, but it's not contactable on the port it usually is. No code has changed so I'm utterly perplexed.

Additionally, nothing is being written to the logs for this container. Normally, in DD, if I click the `web` container I can see the Rails logs as it goes through the boot process etc. DD shows the logs as utterly empty.

Here's my (truncated) Compose file and Dockerfile.

Compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  # web service (connected to local DB)
  web: &web
    container_name: web
    env_file: .env
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 2G
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: /bin/sh -c "rm -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid && gem install bundler -v 2.2.21 && bundle install && rails db:migrate && rails server --port 3000 --binding 0.0.0.0"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ../:/app:cached
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
      - rails_cache:/app/tmp/cache
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - db
    profiles:
      - app
      - appnm

volumes:
  web:
  bundle:
  node_modules:
  rails_cache:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.4
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
ENV APP_HOME /app
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: try `bash`ing inside the container and run the rails server manually, maybe there you can see an error or some log

Comment: I'll try, but why would there be a Rails error suddenly on a container that has always launched successfully until updating Docker?